# Accessing values from an eventListener inside a React Hook with an empty dependancy array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to use React hooks to run a canvas animation that depends on mouse position. I am using a custom hook for mouse position, and wrote another custom hook to animate the canvas.

Placing an empty dependancy array in the animation hook keeps it from unmounting and remounting the animation loop anytime the mouse moves, as is mentioned in [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/) and suggested in a note in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

So the code below works, in that I can access `coords` inside the `drawNow()` function, but mounting and unmounting the animation loop every time the mouse moves does not seem like an acceptable way to do things.

How does one access event listeners inside React hooks that are purposely set to have no dependancies?

Here is the animation and the draw function....

```
const drawNow = (context,coords) => {
    context.fillStyle = '#fff';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(coords.x,coords.y,50,0,2*Math.PI); // need coords here
    context.fill();
}

export const Canvas = () => {
    let ref = React.useRef();

    // custom hook that returns mouse position
    const coords = useMouseMove(); 

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let canvas = ref.current;
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const render = () => {
            aId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
            drawNow(context,coords); // requires current mouse coordinates
        };

        let aId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(aId);
    }, [coords]); // dependancy array should be left blank so requestAnimationFrame mounts only once?

    return (
        <canvas ref={ref}/>
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
        }}
    );
};
```

Here is the custom hook for the mouse coordinates (references this [useEventListener](https://github.com/donavon/use-event-listener/blob/develop/src/index.js))

```
export const useMouseMove = () => {

    function getCoords(clientX,clientY) {
        return {
            x: clientX || 0,
            y: clientY || 0
        };
    }

    const [coords, setCoords] = useState(getCoords);

    useEventListener('mousemove', ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
        setCoords(getCoords(clientX,clientY));
    });
    return coords;
};
```

Thanks, and looking forward to understanding more about hooks and event listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out my problem. The issue is the `useMouseMove()` hook was updating the coordinates with [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), when really I wanted to be using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), allowing me to [imperatively](https://tylermcginnis.com/imperative-vs-declarative-programming/) "modify a child outside the typical data flow", as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

First, I combined the `useMouseMove()` hook with the more general [useEventListener](https://github.com/donavon/use-event-listener/blob/develop/src/index.js) so I didn't have to navigate unnecessary abstractions:

```
// a function that keeps track of mouse coordinates with useState()
export const useMouseMove = () => {

    function getCoords(clientX,clientY) {
        return {
            x: clientX || 0,
            y: clientY || 0
        };
    }

    const [coords, setCoords] = useState(getCoords);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            function handleMove(e) {
                setCoords(getCoords(e.clientX,e.clientY));
            }
            global.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
            return () => {
                global.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
            };
        }
    );
    return coords;
};
```

The next step was to "convert" the above function from `useState()` to `useRef()`:

```
// a function that keeps track of mouse coordinates with useRef()
export const useMouseMove = () => {
    function getCoords(clientX,clientY) {
        return {
            x: clientX || 0,
            y: clientY || 0
        };
    }

    const coords = useRef(getCoords); // ref not state!

    useEffect(
        () => {
            function handleMove(e) {
                coords.current = getCoords(e.clientX,e.clientY);
            }
            global.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
            return () => {
                global.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
            };
        }
    );
    return coords;
};
```

Finally, I can access the mouse coordinates inside the animation loop while also keeping the dependancy array blank, preventing the animation component from remounting every time the mouse moves.

```
// the animation loop that mounts only once with mouse coordinates
export const Canvas = () => {
    let ref = React.useRef();

    // custom hook that returns mouse position
    const coords = useMouseMove();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let canvas = ref.current;
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const render = () => {
            aId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
            drawNow(context,coords.current); // mouse coordinates from useRef()
        };

        let aId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(aId);
    }, []); // dependancy array is blank, the animation loop mounts only once

    return (
        <canvas ref={ref}/>
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
        }}
    );
};
```

Thanks to this escape hatch, I am able to create endless web fun without remounting the animation loop.